# Does react subrender function must return content in the only one external tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some subrender function called from main react render:

```
renderDueDateCell(){
    if(this.props.DueDate != null){
        return(
            <div>
                { this.props.DueDate }
                <i className="icon-shield-notice text-danger ml-5"></i>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return null
}
```

It works fine until I remove external div, which I do not need. Then I go syntax errors which I can't deal with. Is this related to the fact that there must be one most external tag ( in my case this div ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

You can use `Fragment`

```
renderDueDateCell(){
    if(this.props.DueDate != null){
        return(
            <>
                { this.props.DueDate }
                <i className="icon-shield-notice text-danger ml-5"></i>
            </>
        )
    }
    return null
}
```

Note:- [<> is Fragment short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)